# Pandas - unite completing columns

Tags: python, pandas, series

Assuming I'm having the following DataFrame object:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'r1' : [0, 0, 'str1', 'str2', 0 ,0 ,0], 'r2' : ['str1', 'str2', 0, 0, 'str3', 'str4', 'str5']})
df
Out[45]: 
     r1    r2
0     0  str1
1     0  str2
2  str1     0
3  str2     0
4     0  str3
5     0  str4
6     0  str5
```

Where `r1` is "completing" `r2` (when one is `0` the other is a `string`) and vice versa.

What is the fastest way to unite them both and get the following DataFrame:

```
    r_u
0  str1
1  str2
2  str1
3  str2
4  str3
5  str4
6  str5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is important use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
#more general solution 
df = pd.DataFrame({'r1' : [0, 0, 'str1', 'str2', 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 'str7'], 
                   'r2' : ['str1', 'str2', 0, 0, 'str3', 'str4', 'str5', 0, 'str8']})
print (df)
     r1    r2
0     0  str1
1     0  str2
2  str1     0
3  str2     0
4     0  str3
5     0  str4
6     0  str5
7     0     0 
8  str7  str8
```

If both `0` expected output is define in `default` parameter and if strings in both is possible prioritize them by order of masks and columns:

```
m1 = df['r1'] != 0
m2 = df['r2'] != 0
df['r3'] = np.select([m1, m2], [df['r1'], df['r2']], default=None)
df['r4'] = np.select([m2, m1], [df['r2'], df['r1']], default=None)

print (df)
     r1    r2    r3    r4
0     0  str1  str1  str1
1     0  str2  str2  str2
2  str1     0  str1  str1
3  str2     0  str2  str2
4     0  str3  str3  str3
5     0  str4  str4  str4
6     0  str5  str5  str5
7     0     0  None  None
8  str7  str8  str7  str8
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`pd.Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html), followed by [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) accessor:

```
df['r3'] = df.mask(df.eq(0)).ffill(1).iloc[:, -1]

print(df)

     r1    r2    r3
0     0  str1  str1
1     0  str2  str2
2  str1     0  str1
3  str2     0  str2
4     0  str3  str3
5     0  str4  str4
6     0  str5  str5
```

For a small additional speed-up, you can use NumPy arrays for comparison, i.e. replace `df.eq(0)` with `df.values == 0`.

Comment: Took: 0.87. nice answer though. Jezrael took 0.10s

Comment: @EranMoshe, Sure. I mean, by all means choose the faster answer if this is really your bottleneck. It's worth also considering maintainability / extendibility, if these are also concerns.

Comment: You are correct but this is a "patch" that will last for about 30-60 days and will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['r3']=(df['r1'].astype(str) + df['r2'].astype(str)).str.replace('0', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of diversity - you could also use `df.lookup()`:

```
df['r3'] = df.lookup(df.index, [['r1', 'r2'][int(v==0)] for v in df.r1])
```

However, this is not the fastest solution, for afaik @jezrael posted the fastest one:

timeit results for 10000 repetitions:

```
lookup
3.846349009425694

mask
18.704440796350127

np.select
2.7935229356389755

str.replace
6.296438898734323
```